# How to convert string to number in php?

Tags: javascript, php

How to convert string to number in **PHP**?

Could any one tell me how to convert string data to number?

For example:

```
$Str = "212315"; // convert to 212315
```

Comment: It is a number.  What do you actually need?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cast it to an integer.

```
(int) $Str;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting

> To explicitly convert a value to integer, use either the (int) or (integer) casts. However, in most cases the cast is not needed, since a value will be automatically converted if an operator, function or control structure requires an integer argument. A value can also be converted to integer with the intval() function.

Comment: why?
can you describe to me?

Comment: look at my edited answer. An integer is a number.

Answer (score 2):

you can do several things

```
$str = "212315";

$int = intval($str);

$int2 = (int) $str;

$int3 = (integer) $str;
```